# How to make balls ignore collisions with each other

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

With sprite kit, I'm trying to make series of balls drop from the air through physics simulation, and I want them to drop without colliding with each other and bounce off. I just want them to go straight down and pass through each other. How should I make this happen with `collisionBitMask` and `categoryBitMask` ?

```
// Common.h
#ifndef Rainy_Poops_common_h
#define Rainy_Poops_common_h

static int poopSize_x = 20; 
static int poopSize_y = 20;
static const uint32_t poopCategory = 0x1 << 1;
#endif

// MyScene.h
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
_timer++;
if (_timer % 3 == 0) {
    SKSpriteNode * p = [[Poop alloc] init];
    NSInteger random_x = arc4random_uniform([[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.width);
    p.position = CGPointMake(random_x, [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.height - 5);
    [self addChild: p];

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"poop" usingBlock:
     ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
         Poop *poop = (Poop *) node;

         if (!poop.isDropping) {
             poop.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(poopSize_x, poopSize_y)];
             poop.isDropping = YES;
         }

         if (poop.position.y < 0) {
             [poop removeFromParent];
         }
     }];
   }
}

#import "Poop.h"

@implementation Poop
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"poop2.png"];
    self.isDropping = NO;

    self.name = @"poop";
    self.size = CGSizeMake(poopSize_x, poopSize_y);

    SKPhysicsBody *physicsPoop = self.physicsBody;
    physicsPoop.collisionBitMask = 0;
    physicsPoop.categoryBitMask = poopCategory;
    physicsPoop.affectedByGravity = YES;
    physicsPoop.mass = 100;
    physicsPoop.allowsRotation = NO;
    physicsPoop.dynamic = YES;

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: You should update your question to show what you have tried and the relevant code.

Comment: Just did, have a look

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  Post the text and then press the {} button in the question editor - it will convert it to code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to this line -

```
poop.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(poopSize_x,poopSize_y)];
```

You initialise your `categoryBitMask` to 2 and `collisionBitMask` to 0 in the init of your node, but this line will reset the physicsBody for your poop and assign the default `collisionBitMask` and `categoryBitMask` values of `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks for the great advices :)

Answer (score 0):

set collisionButMask equal to 0 for no collision or equal to the categoryBitMask of the sprite you would like the balls to collide with.

Comment: I answered your question when you included 0 code.  Your code did not set the values in the correct location as Paulw has pointed out.